# Why does `clang++ -fuse-ld=lld main.cpp` not work?

Tags: c++, linux, clang, llvm, lld

I installed `clang-10` and `lld-10`, but I cannot use `lld` as the linker.

messages:

```
[root@mine ~]# ll /usr/local/bin/lld
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 79005720 Mar 26 14:26 /usr/local/bin/lld

[root@mine ~]# ll /usr/local/bin/ld.lld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Mar 26 14:51 /usr/local/bin/ld.lld -> lld

[root@mine ~]# lld -v
lld is a generic driver.
Invoke ld.lld (Unix), ld64.lld (macOS), lld-link (Windows), wasm-ld (WebAssembly) instead

[root@mine ~]# ld.lld -v
LLD 10.0.0 (compatible with GNU linkers)

[root@mine ~]# cat main.cpp
int main() {}

[root@mine ~]# clang++ -fuse-ld=lld main.cpp
ld.lld: error: cannot open output file a.out: Function not implemented
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Why does `lld-10` not work?**

If I use `ld` rather than `lld`:

`[root@mine ~]# clang++ -fuse-ld=ld main.cpp`

then everything is ok!

Comment: Do you get any extra information if you add `-v` to your compilation command?

Comment: I have tried as you recommend, but no helpful information.

Comment: Run the build command with `strace -f` and add the last few lines of the output to your question. (There should be one line indicating an error followed by multiple more error reporting and cleanup ones, which are not really helpful.) Also: Did you build `lld` yourself or did you install a binary package? If the latter, did you make sure that the binary supports your OS/Distribution?

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. My clang works with gold and ld linker but not with lld.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lld` needs to know how to parse arguments, which it determines based on which binary name you use: https://groups.google.com/g/llvm-dev/c/k3q_ATl-K_0/m/MjEb6gsCCAAJ

You need to use `ld.lld` as the binary name.